# Why can't I use assertTrue in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I am trying to run the following code in R2016a

```
import matlab.unittest.qualifications.Assertable;
assertTrue(true, 'wrong');
```

But am getting this error.

> Undefined function or variable 'assertTrue'.

I did not notice any changes in `assertTrue` of Matlab 2016a.
I also tried unsuccessfully the import of `matlab.unittest.qualifications.*`. 
I also tried unsuccessfully `testcase.assertTrue(true, 'wrong');`.

---

How can you I use assertTrue in Matlab?

Comment: MATLAB has import now? im so confused!

Comment: @AnderBiguri MATLAB has pretty much always had [`import`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html)

Comment: @excaza MATLAB had import before? im so confused!

Comment: @AnderBiguri: introduced some years ago http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012b/matlab/ref/import.html?searchHighlight=import

Comment: I was able to import `assertTrue()` with `import matlab.unittest.*` on R2015b

Comment: @Masi nothing is wrong. It needs to be passed a `matlab.unittest.TestCase`

Comment: @Alessiox Can you please given a complete example. `import matlab.unittest.*;` is not sufficient. How do you import `assertTrue()` with the package?

Comment: @Masi, don't ask me why. But with the three commands `import matlab.unittest.*; matlab.unittest.qualifications; help assertTrue;` finally `assertTrue` is recognized (the help pops up). The second instruction, however, throws an error. Well weird.

Comment: And if you substitute the line `import matlab.unittest.*` with your import line, still the same behaviour: error thrown, but `assertTrue` recognized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assertTrue` is not a vanilla MATLAB function, it is a *method* of [`matlab.unittest.TestCase`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase-class.html).

[Notice in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.assertable.asserttrue.html#inputarg_assertable), that the first input (`assertable`) is a `matlab.unittest.TestCase` instance.

It is used like this in a [class-based unit test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-simple-test-case-using-classes.html)

```
classdef test < matlab.unittest.TestCase

    methods (Test)
        function doTest(testCase)
            testCase.assertTrue(true);

            % or
            assertTrue(testCase, true);
        end
    end
end
```

and this in a [function-based unit test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-function-based-unit-tests-.html)

```
function testFunctionOne(testCase)
    testCase.assertTrue(true)
    assertTrue(testCase, true)
end
```

If you don't want unit tests but simply want to assert that something is true, then use [`assert`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assert.html).

```
value = false;
assert(value, 'These aren''t the droids you''re looking for.')
```

Comment: @Masi unit tests are a very different use case from just wanting to assert that something is true. The first is good for validating your code's correctness, the second is good for validating inputs and such in the normal flow of a program.

Comment: @Masi Look at my answer again. `testCase` is **not** an inequality it is a [`matlab.unittest.TestCase`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase-class.html) instance. I think you probably just want `assert` like my last example shows the way you're describing it.

Comment: @Masi are you actually doing a unit test? You shouldn't just pick functions out of a hat based on their name...

Comment: @excaza Yes, I need to do them. I am just confused by this statement `import matlab.unittest.*;` and importing `assertTrue` with it because I cannot get it work.

Comment: @Masi as I said. I **THINK** you want `assert`. Can you show us the complete code of where you are trying to use it? As far as how to use `assertTrue`, I have given you two complete examples.

Comment: @Masi you don't need to import `assertTrue`. The [test runner](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testrunner-class.html) will automatically pass `testCase` to your function or class.

Comment: @Masi just [start here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html) and go read for a little bit. Feel free to come back and ask questions if you have any (in a different thread)

Comment: You are right! I had initially `assert` but I wanted to make my tests as tight as possible to hit over the boundary too much.

Comment: @Masi if you're *actually* doing unit tests (real unit tests using the MATLAB unit test framework) don't use `assert`. You *would* want `assertTrue` but you need to read a little bit to understand how to use it properly. You're not going to get it to work by just typing anything into the command line.